# Getting element by id and then changing the onClick attribute in JSX

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I am using JavaScript and JSX in React. I am trying to change element's onClick values in my JavaScript. This is how I am attempting it:

```
document.getElementById(id).onClick = this.selectCardsFromBoard;
```

I know that the `document.getElementById(id)` is accessing the correct element, but it is not adding any onClick attribute to it. When I include the attribute `onClick` in the jsx originally, it works, but I can't change the `onClick` to a different function. There are also no problems with the function `this.selectCardsFromBoard`. Any suggestions?

Comment: why you want to change the function ? any specific reason ?

Comment: You are mixing native DOM API and react. DOM has 'onclick' property. Still there is no reason to mix things. You could use React to change handler.

Comment: BTW https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: different reasons might lead to different solutions here. If you want to add and remove events directly to/from the DOM elements, aren't addEventListener/removeEventListener enough? Or alternatively you can use the parent component's state to control children components' onClick.

Comment: when /on what place are your trying to change the `listener` ?

Comment: addEventListener is what I was looking for. Thank you.